# VueJS - Web History | Selection/deselection of checkboxes based on URL parameters | Keep selection on page refresh

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am currently trying to create small functionality and I need some help.

I have the bunch of checkbox filters. On every checkbox click I am making API request to retrieve the data back.

```
apiQS: function() {
  return '?pageIndex=' + this.pageIndex + '&pageSize=' + this.pageSize + 
    this.brandCheck() + this.colourCheck() + this.priceCheck()
},
constructApiURL: function (){
  return this.apiBase + this.apiQS();
}

<template>
 <ul>
  <li v-for="(price, index) in prices" v-bind:key="index">
   <input type="checkbox" name="prices" v-bind:value="price.qsValue" v-model="checked" v-on:change="changePrices()" v-bind:disabled="price.facetHits === 0">{{price.facetName}} ({{price.facetHits}})
  </li>

  {{checked}}
 </ul>
</template>
```

I am also using 'window.history.pushState' function to see all selected checkboxes in URL

```
history.pushState(null, null, this.apiQS());
```

My questions would be:

- How to keep all selected checkboxes on page refresh
- How to deselect/select checkboxes when user goes back/forward based on URL parameters

***NOTE: This project does not use jQuery. Solution must be either VUEJS or pure JavaScript***

Comment: Do you use `vue-router`?

Comment: No. All routing will be handled by ASP.net MVC core 2